# IP changes while pinging IPV6 address

Tags: windows, ipv6, tunnel

I have made a small demo program to sniff IPV6 packets  . I am trying to ping the said machine from a remote  one . My site local address is "FEC0..." and Link local address is "FE80..." . However , when i ping the machine and view the destination address of the ping packet , the address is sometimes "FeC0..." , sometimes "Fe80..." and even "FF02.." at times. I cannot understand why it would ping to a IP different from the specified one. I specify the destination address as "FEC0...".

Can someone please explain this ?

Here is my output of "ipconfig /all"

Windows IP Configuration

```
    Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : PT49
    Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
    Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcast
    IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
    WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
```

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 3:

```
    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 38-60-77-87-02-4B
    Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
    IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.249
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
    IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0::1:3a60:77ff:fe87:24b%1
    IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : fe80::3a60:77ff:fe87:24b%4
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1
    DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.96
                                        fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                        fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                        fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
```

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

```
    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF
    Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
    IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : fe80::5445:5245:444f%5
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
    NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

Tunnel adapter Automatic Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

```
    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Automatic Tunneling Pseudo-Interface

    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : C0-A8-02-F9
    Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
    IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : fe80::5efe:192.168.2.249%2
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
    DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                        fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                        fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
    NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're probably pinging a broadcast address.

Comment: @PaulR : FEC0 is not a broadcast address as per i know .

Comment: btw. fec0 (site-local) addresses are deprecated. You should use UA addresses instead. Also when you say it pinfs fec0 address, which one is that ? Maybe it does not ping it but tries to resolve hostname with one of DNSs

Comment: @Dārayavahuštdi : The ip address i specify is fec0::1:3a60:77ff:fe87:24b%1". can you explain about "resolve hostname with one of DNSs" part ?

Comment: @PaulR : Maybe it is creating a multicast packet because "FF02" is multicast packet .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange results are not surprising as you don't really have IPv6 connectivity (I'm not seeing any global unicast address in your ipconfig), get a tunnel+subnet from SixXS and try again :)